# How to prove $Y=X^{2}$ is Beta$\left(0.5,\ 1\right)$ if $X$ is Uniform$(0,\ 1)$

Tags: uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, beta-distribution

[image]

I've been reading about uniform distributions but I can't see how $Y=X^{2}$ is Beta$\left(0.5,\ 1\right)$ if $X$ is Uniform$(0,\ 1)$. Is there a way to prove this using the cumulative distribution function method?

My attempt:

[image]

Comment: x=rnunif(0,1), y=x^2, ks.test(y,"pbeta",0.5,1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is incredibly straightforward.  The CDF of $Y$ is $\mbox{Pr} \left[Y \le y \right]$.  Now substitute $Y$ for $X^2$ and square root both sides to obtain $\mbox{Pr} \left[X \le \sqrt{y}\right]$.  The square root operator is a one-to-one transformation for the domain $(0,1)$.  Now the CDF of $X$ is  $\mbox{Pr} \left[X \le x\right] =x$.  Replace $x$ with $\sqrt{y}$ to obtain that the CDF of $Y$ is $\sqrt{y}$.  This is equivalent to the regularized incomplete beta function $I_y(.5,1)$, the CDF of a $Beta(.5,1)$ random variable.

Comment: I'm kinda confused how you got that last bit (equivalent to the regularized incomplete beta function). I tried writing it out above. What should I write next?

Comment: Sorry I was away.  I only wrote the relation involving the regularized incomplete beta function since it is the standard way of denoting the CDF of a $Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ random variable.  Note, $I_x (\alpha,\beta) = \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)} \int_0^x t^{\alpha-1} (1-t)^{\beta-1} \mbox{d} t$.  Hence, when $\beta=1$, the integral can be expressed in closed form since we know the anti-derivative of $t^{\alpha-1}$.  See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties_2

Comment: Thank you! If X was Beta(0.5, 1), how would you derive the distribution of Y = 1 − X?

Comment: Use the same CDF technique and make the substitution $Y=1-X$.  Note that $I_x(1,\beta) = 1 - (1-x)^{\beta}$.  You should find that $Y \sim Beta(1,.5)$.  Also when typing equations on this website, it uses LaTeX code.  Just enclose all math equations in two dollar signs \$ matheq \$

Comment: How did you get "CDF of Y is $ \sqrt{y}$"?

Comment: Is it because of the one-to-one transformation so you can just sub it in?

Comment: Yes, in this case everything is one-to-one.  For more difficult patterns you must partition the mapping into a set of one-to-one transformations.  For instance if $Z=X^2$ when $X$, the baseline distribution, can be positive or negative then there are two one-to-one transformations.  For $X>0$, we have $X=\sqrt{Z}$, and for $X<0$, we have $X=-\sqrt{Z}$

Comment: You explained the answer and the comments very nicely! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

A $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution has support on $[0,1]$ with density proportional to $x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}$.

You have found that $F_Y(y)=y^{0.5}$ when $0<y<1$

so its density is the derivative $f(y)=0.5y^{-0.5} = 0.5y^{0.5-1}(1-y)^{1-1}$

which is clearly a $\text{Beta}(0.5,1)$ density

Comment: Thank you! If X was Beta(0.5, 1), how would you derive the distribution of Y = 1 − X?

Comment: @pellypen  If $X \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ and $Y=1-X$ then $Y \sim \text{Beta}(\beta,\alpha)$

Comment: Is there a way to prove that using cumulative distribution function method? My attempt so far: $F_{1-X}(\alpha)= P(1-X \leq \alpha) = P(1-\alpha \leq X) = P(X\geq 1-\alpha) =1-F_X(1-\alpha)$

Comment: I can't see why $=1-P(X\leq 1-y) =1-F_X(1-y) = Y \sim \text{Beta}(\beta,\alpha)$

Comment: I would not use $\alpha$ as it means something else in a Beta distribution.  And it is more obvious with a change of variable in the density:  if $y=1-x$ then a density proportional to $x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}$ also has a density proportional to $y^{\beta-1}(1-y)^{\alpha-1}$

Comment: How did you get $y=1-x$?

Comment: @pellypen: (a) you asked $F_{1-X}(\alpha)= P(1-X \leq \alpha) = \cdots$ so I assumed you wanted to about $1-x$.  (b) working with the Beta distribution, the density is easier to handle than the CDF

Comment: ah sorry, I just cant see it. How did you convert back to the density?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $10,000$ observations `x` from $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$
Then square them. About $1000$ of these $x$-values will
lie in $(0,0.1]$ and their squares will lie in the interval
$(0,0.01].$ In the histograms below both bars are colored
red. [The red bar on the right is tall and thin, so
you may have to look closely to see it is colored red.]

similarly about $1000$ of these $x$-values will lie in
$(0.9, 1]$ and their squares will lie in the interval
$(0.81, 1].$ In the histograms below both bars are colored violet. So the original points and their images
under transformation lie in bars of the same color.
Each bar in each histogram contains about $1000$ observations,
and each bar has area $0.1.$ Heights of the bars on the right differ because the widths of their bases differ.

The histgram on the right is consistent with
a sample from $\mathsf{Beta}(0.5,1),$ as shown
by the density function (black).

```
set.seed(2022)
x = runif(10^5)
y = x^2
```

[image]

R code for the figure is shown below:

```
farb = rainbow(11)[1:10]
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
cutp = seq(0,1, by=.1)
 hdr1 = "Density of UNIF(0,1)"
 hist(x, ylim=c(0,10), prob=T, br=cutp, col=farb, main=hdr1)
  curve(dunif(x), add=T, lwd=2)
 hdr2 = "Density of BETA(.5.1)"
 hist(y, prob=T, br=cutp^2, col=farb, main=hdr2)
  curve(dbeta(x,.5,1), add=T, lwd=2)
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```